# os.path.isfile only recognizes some files but not all

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, csv

OS: Windows 10

---

If I have the python script within `C:/Temp/CSV` It works as it should. However, if i have the script in a separate folder, it only recognizes one of the three `.csv` files.

```py
import os
search_dir='C:/Temp/CSV'
files1 =os.listdir(search_dir)
files2 = filter(os.path.isfile, files1)
print(files1,'\n')
for f in files2:
    print(f)
```

This is the output if I place the scripit in a separate folder:

```
['desktop.ini', 'CsvFile1.csv', 'CsvFile2.csv', 'CsvFile3.csv'] 

desktop.ini
CsvFile1.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `files1` you have a list of filenames, but the path is missing. So in `files2 = filter(os.path.isfile, files1)` you check the files in the current working directory. Add the path before checking with `os.path.isfile`.

```
files2 = filter(os.path.isfile, [os.path.join(search_dir, filename) for filename in files1])
```